# I need to fix my URL Rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am making my User Profiles redirect to `/username`.

I have other directories like `/about` and `/chat` and `/poll`, etc.

When I went to: `/about`, it made it to: `/about/?member=about`.

This is what I have in my `.htaccess` to redirect the profile:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ profile.php?member=$1 [L]
```

I don't want my about page to be `/about/?member=about` because `about` is not a member and it's explaining what my community is.

I can do `/user/Username`, but I don't know how to do that and I don't know if that will still affect my other directories.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed myself, for anyone who may want future reference:

I just made it rewrite to a different directory so it would disturb my /about, etc. I made it rewrite to /u, /user, and /member just so if people don't remember which one to use they can give it a guess.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule u/(.*)/ profile.php?member=$1
RewriteRule u/(.*) profile.php?member=$1
RewriteRule user/(.*)/ profile.php?member=$1
RewriteRule user/(.*) profile.php?member=$1
RewriteRule member/(.*)/ profile.php?member=$1
RewriteRule member/(.*) profile.php?member=$1
```

Comment: Whilst that works, you'd probably be better off using this: `RewriteRule ^(u|user|member)/(.*)/? profile.php?member=$1 [L]`. Just merging the different *options* and making the trailing slash optional.